# Software RealTime-Monitoring Tool

Tags: c#, performance, operating-system, monitor

For my final test in C# course I have to retrieve PC performance indicators in real time such as CPU and RAM usage, free hard disk percentage, network bytes sent and received, uptime, and number of running processes.
Are there any pre-buit class-libraries to monitor and store these parameters? In all cases, how can I get these infos from the Operative System?

Comment: You would use WMI (System.Management) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any pre-buit class-library to monitor and store these parameters?

Yes, there is. Operating system tracks hundreds of performance metrics while it executes different threads and Interrupt Requests. These metrics are available for querying using either Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) or Performance Counters. Performance counters are probably easier in terms of syntax and boilerplate coding.

Search for specifics to get source example, e.g. [performance counter C# CPU usage](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=performance+counter+C%23+CPU&oq=performance+counter+C%23+CPU)